# VegasJS are not working with bower

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to use [VegasJS](https://vegas.jaysalvat.com/) as a slider, and Bower o manage my packages, but I am not able to run the vegas using bower, and Vegas aren't working at all, I tried to use without bower too, but was not successfully. It only occurs in my localserver, because I rewrite the exact same code in [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OpxXWO), and it works perfectly.

I'm using Gulp too, don't know if it will make some difference.

My HTML code:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/normalize-css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/vegas/dist/vegas.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
    <!-- JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../bower_components/vegas/dist/vegas.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../bower_components/owl.carousel/dist/owl.carousel.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <header>
    </header>

</body>
```

The CSS code:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box; }

header {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: crimson; }
```

The JavaScript code:

```
$("header").vegas({
    slides: [
        { src: "https://unsplash.it/1000x1000?image=421" },
        { src: "https://unsplash.it/1000x1000?image=500" },
        { src: "https://unsplash.it/1000x1000?image=425" },
        { src: "https://unsplash.it/1000x1000?image=261" }
    ]
});
```

Gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('./public/sass/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass.sync().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/css'))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

gulp.task('browser-sync', ['sass'], function() {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: "public",
            routes: {
                "/bower_components": "bower_components"
            }
        }
    });

    gulp.watch('./public/sass/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
    gulp.watch('./public/*.html').on('change', browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch('./public/js/*.js').on('change', browserSync.reload);
});

gulp.task('autoprefixer', function() {
    gulp.src('./public/css/style.css')
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
            "browserslist": [
                "Chrome",
                "Firefox",
                "Explorer",
                "Edge",
                "iOS",
                "Opera",
                "Safari",
                "ExplorerMobile",
                "last 3 versions",
                "> 1%"
            ],
            cascade: false
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/css'))
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('./public/css/*.css', ['autoprefixer']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['sass', 'browser-sync', 'autoprefixer', 'watch']);
```

Everything seems to be working very well, with exception of Vegas, I don't know why in my localserver it aren't working.

In this case, I tested the Owl Carousel, and its working perfectly well, the only problem here, are the Vegas. I almost certainly the problem are on css link.

I tested in WebStorm and Atom IDE by the way.

Thanks for all the help, but I fixed it, what happens was, I commited the mistake of add the initialization without document ready property, the right way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("header").vegas({
        slides: [
            { src: "https://unsplash.it/1000x1000?image=421" },
            { src: "https://unsplash.it/1000x1000?image=500" },
            { src: "https://unsplash.it/1000x1000?image=425" },
            { src: "https://unsplash.it/1000x1000?image=261" }
        ]
    });
});
```

Comment: can ou share you gulp/grunt config file?

Comment: any errors in your browser's console? if you look at your browser's network tab do you see request for vegas.min.js? what is the response (is it the minified vendor file?

Comment: @ValterJunior Yes, I already edited with the gulp file

Comment: @pQuestions123 Any errors in console, all of them in 304, GET is ok, the browser can make the requests/responses successfully, I'm using the minfied file, but I tried the two.